# How to add a child via PHP in xml string with soap tag

Tags: php, xml, soap, xml-parsing

Im trying to add a Child in articoli node but when i execute the code i receive this error, what I'm doing wrong?

> SimpleXMLElement::addChild(): Cannot add child. Parent is not a
>   permanent member of the XML tree

```
   <?php
    $note='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soap12:Body>
      <AddPrenotazione>
          <sessionId>6355aa2c-21f5-4436-8fef-24f0211bbd86</sessionId>
          <guid>4353999998999999</guid>
          <articoli>
          </articoli>
        </AddPrenotazione>
        </soap12:Body>
    </soap12:Envelope>';

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($note);
    $xml->children('soap12', true)->Body->articoli->addChild("ArticoloPrenotazione","");

    echo $xml->asXML();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure of the XML when setting the value needs a couple of extra parts...

```
$xml->children('soap12', true)->Body->children()
          ->AddPrenotazione->articoli->addChild("ArticoloPrenotazione","");
```

You missed out the `AddPrenotazione` level, but as this is in a different namespaces to the `Body` element you also need to use `children()` to fetch the elements from the default namespace.